# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' (NodeJS Angular Universal Server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular-universal

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
```

When running my nodejs server main.js in order to use Angular Universal (Most basic server.ts for universal, listening on port 443). Does anybody know how to fix this or how to debug this?

I updated to node 18.18.0, but that didnt help. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: I got something similar lately. Make sure your use the same node version to build your angular app as the one running on your server